# Create a Lead vaildation rule that disallows moving backwards but with a few exceptions

Tags: formula, leads

Given the Lead Statuses I have, and in the order they appear, I need to be able to accomplish two things with a validation rule:

## 1 In general no lead status can change backwards with the exception of

## 2 The **“Unqualified”** and **“Re-Market”** statuses should be able to be change back to the **“MQL – Follow Up”** status and only that status

The below validation rule accomplishes #1 fine in that in general backwards movement of lead status gets trapped by the validation rule, however with #2  All Prior Values are allowed to be reset back to “MQL - Follow Up” instead of just the “Unqualified” and “Re-Market” values.

Just to clarify with an example: the **“Customer”** status should never be able to move backwards but with this validation in place it can erroneously be reset to “MQL – Follow Up”.

Can anyone spot what needs to change in the validation rule below to achieve the above described?

---

```
CASE( Status ,
"Open",1,
"New",2,
"MQL - Follow Up",3,
"In Progress",4,
"In Progress - Further Activity",5,
"Re-Market",6,
"Unqualified",7,
"Non-Prospect",8,
"Wrong Contact",9,
"No Longer w/Co",10,
"Remove",11,
"Qualified",12,
"Customer",13,
"Approved",14,0)
<
CASE(PRIORVALUE(Status) ,
"Open",1,
"New",2,
"MQL - Follow Up",3,
"In Progress",4,
"In Progress - Further Activity",5,
"Re-Market",6,
"Unqualified",7,
"Non-Prospect",8,
"Wrong Contact",9,
"No Longer w/Co",10,
"Remove",11,
"Qualified",12,
"Customer",13,
"Approved",14,0) && (TEXT(Status) != 'MQL - Follow Up' && (PRIORVALUE(Status) != 'Re-Market' || PRIORVALUE(Status) != 'Unqualified'))
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a go and see if it helps ..

all it says is first check if the status is changed from **Re-Market or Unqualified to MQL-Follow Up**, if yes skip the validation, otherwise go thru your validation

```
IF( 
  AND(
    TEXT(Status) = 'MQL - Follow Up',  
    OR(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status)) = 'Re-Market',TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status)) = 'Unqualified') 
  ),
  FALSE,
  CASE( Status ,
  "Open",1,
  "New",2,
  "MQL - Follow Up",3,
  "In Progress",4,
  "In Progress - Further Activity",5,
  "Re-Market",6,
  "Unqualified",7,
  "Non-Prospect",8,
  "Wrong Contact",9,
  "No Longer w/Co",10,
  "Remove",11,
  "Qualified",12,
  "Customer",13,
  "Approved",14,0)
  <
  CASE(PRIORVALUE(Status) ,
  "Open",1,
  "New",2,
  "MQL - Follow Up",3,
  "In Progress",4,
  "In Progress - Further Activity",5,
  "Re-Market",6,
  "Unqualified",7,
  "Non-Prospect",8,
  "Wrong Contact",9,
  "No Longer w/Co",10,
  "Remove",11,
  "Qualified",12,
  "Customer",13,
  "Approved",14,0)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick but then our marketing folks decided not to put the validation rule in to play!